# how to call PopupMenu menu on actionbar button click in android

Tags: android

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.backicon:

        return true;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.visitmenu, menu);
    return true;
}

private void showFilterPopup(View v) {
    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
    // Inflate the menu from xml
    popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_filters, popup.getMenu());
    // Setup menu item selection
    popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.menu_keyword:
                Toast.makeText(EmployeeVisit.this, "Keyword!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            case R.id.menu_popularity:
                Toast.makeText(EmployeeVisit.this, "Popularity!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            default:
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    popup.show();

}
```

this is my code i want to display popupmenu on actionbar menu click please tell me how to apply click and show popupmenu on buttton click but i am unable to call   case R.id.backicon: showFilterPopup(view v) what i should pass please help me

Answer (score 0):

**Try below code:**

In your required view Onclick,

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                popUpView.setAnchorView(v);
                popUpView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                        switch (position) {
                            case 0:
                                popUpView.dismiss();
                                // do someThing();
                                break;
                            case 1:
                                popUpView.dismiss();
                                // do someThing();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                });
                popUpView.show();
            }
```